# angular2 ngmodel can't bind the value i wish

Tags: angular, events, typescript, ngmodel

this is my html template code:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" 
    [(ngModel)]="groupInfo.discount" (keyup)="validateFloat($event)">
```

there is my validateFloat method:

```
validateFloat(event){
   event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
   console.log(this.groupInfo.discount);
}
```

then when input value:

```
12adc
```

input element output value:

```
 12
```

but the groupInfo.discount value is:

```
 12a
```

i can't understand why the groupInfo.discount value is `12a`?

And how can i make the groupInfo.discount value is equal to input element's value?

my package dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
```

Comment: what are you trying to do can you explain a little bit ?

Comment: i wish groupInfo.discount value is equal input element's value

Answer (score 1):

if you are using input && ngModel in template better than `(keyup)` use `(ngModelChange)` event

`template.html`

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" 
[(ngModel)]="groupInfo.discount" (ngModelChange)="validateFloat($event)">
```

I thinks its only the `trigger issue` with `event`

Comment: As per i Know there is only a differenve of one value. In your example there is a difference of two. Whats your Angular version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your update isn't being picked up by ngModel properly.

Try doing your update asynchronously like this:

```
validateFloat(event){
   setTimeout(() => {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    console.log(this.groupInfo.discount);
   }, 50);
}
```

ngModel has some unintuitive behaviour when you try to get fancy with it because of what it's trying to do - (reflect changes in your component to the DOM and changes to the DOM in your component). Because Angular doesn't allow you to change a value after it's checked during a change detection cycle, ngModel has to work asynchronously, which can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: groupInfo.discount value is not equal input element's value